# how do i change the default gps location on genymotion?

Tags: android, gps, genymotion, genymotion-gps

It's a real drag (heh) to drag the GPS all the way from Iceland to England each time I boot the VM in Genymotion. Any idea on how I can change the default location for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's the behavior for the "Personal Use" license. The Business or Indie licenses keeps the last GPS position in memory when you turn the device off.

You can also change the GPS position through command line with these paid modes.

BTW, it is not just Iceland's position, it is Dalvik ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After I read this qustion and answer of eyal-lezmy, for a couple of days I thought that how can I overcome this issue . Then I found a solution.

An app might be use that provide a fake location for android.

I use [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=tr). Now I don't use built-in GPS menu of Genymotion.

This is useful when testing my app.

Thanks eyal-lezmy. (I've given reputation)